# Android SurfaceView and animated graphics

Tags: android, imageview, surfaceview

I want to make a "2d game" using graphics from the ressources for the characters.
Now I'm asking myself what is the best solution.

I was searching a lot in the net finding the two different options.

- A) Creating a custom view, adding it to the layout showing a AnimationDrawable or
- B) Using the SurfaceView directly painting on it

Whereas a) is usually called slow and unperformant for games I tried to find a solution for b).
But so far all tutorials are only made with one image moving around on the surfaceView or animating geometric shapes (which isn't really what I had in mind).
Finding tutorials for "how to draw AnimationDrawable on SurfaceView" are very rare.

So I thought I might load all animation frames of my character into an array drawing each call the right one on the SurfaceView. But that sounds like a lot of overhead to me. Should I abandon the SurfaceView?

Has anyone a good idea what would be the best way to animate - lets say 10 characters + "background" on my screen?

Comment: There are ready to use libs/frameworks for Android using GL and such. If you want to go with SurfaceView, implement your own Sprite classes and such, using the Android components cold be messy for that.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to use openGL since it is "only" a 2D game. More like the typical jump&run game. Actually, all I need is something like a way to draw the AnimationDrawable on a SurfaceView but that doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: the use of GL does not imply there´ll be 3d gfx and the GL rendering is waaaaay faster. AnimationDrawable may be cool for a button with sfx, animating such a thing moving on screen WILL be messy.

Comment: Hm, true. Even though I think I fould a good way of doing it. I did some OpenGL before and it always felt like a huge overhead for even showing a simple 2D sprite. Not sure if I did it wrong though...

Comment: @TobiasReich, so what decision you choose? I'm in the begging of game development and this question in my head too.

Comment: Uh, that was 5 years ago. Honestly I don't remember very well but I think I used a surfaceview. At least I would today since it gives better control over my own "draw objects". Downside is you need to organise your data on your own (a bit like using OpenGL and managing collision etc. by yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) three options:

1. Draw on SurfaceView surface with a Canvas.  This will use software rendering and be relatively slow.
2. Instead of a SurfaceView, draw on a custom View with a Canvas.  This will be hardware accelerated, with [some limitations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).
3. Draw on SurfaceView surface with OpenGL ES.  This will be hardware accelerated, but you have to figure out how GLES works.

You should also consider (4) use an open-source 2D game engine and don't worry about what it's actually doing.

If you want an example, [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/) is a simple but complete 2D game written for GLES and GLSurfaceView.  A more evolved set of EGL/GLES helpers can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), which uses GLSurfaceView, SurfaceView, and TextureView to accomplish various things.  It also demonstrates the use of the hardware scaler to improve efficiency on larger displays.

Long description of the Android graphics architecture is available [here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: Hey thanks. So you say, drawing to the SurfaceView is slower than using AnimationDrawable creating separate views? I thought it would be the other way around. I read somewhere that using Views has a lot of overhead!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html states that the canvas (from the surfaceView I'm drawing at) is also hardware accellerated. Or isn't it?

Comment: A SurfaceView has two parts, the "surface" and the "view".  The View part is just a transparent place-holder used for layout with other Views; the Surface is a completely separate layer that sits behind the layer with the Views in it.  Rendering is done to the Surface.  You *could* render to the View part of a SurfaceView, but that would be pointless (and a waste of system resources).  In any event, Canvas rendering to a View is accelerated, Canvas rendering to a Surface is not.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't know that. So I can also use view elements on the surfaceView. Well, I think this comes close to what I was looking for. So drawing on the surface but using views (buttons, click events...) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not sure this is the best option but I found a tutorial for using "Sprite Sheets".

http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame4.html

So far this seems to be a good solution. OpenGL seemed a bit too much to me but perhaps I'm not good at Shader Language etc.
So if anyone finds a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: It looks really good! BTW you don´t need such knowledge of 3d programming when u use http://www.andengine.org/ or such.